# How to join two columns (one is list other is integer id column ) in pandas python in one dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, join

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ptVi1.png]

[image]

I want to join these two columns in a new Dataframe like this:

[image]

Comment: Can you please provide reproducible `DataFrame` constructors of the inputs? Images are not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`join` and `explode`:

```
out = (df_id.join(df_cast['Cast'].str.split(',\s*'))
        .explode('Cast')
     )
```

Or `explode` and `join`:

```
out = df_id.join(df_cast['Cast'].str.split(',\s*').explode('Cast'))
```